# Word2Vec doesnt_match function throws Numpy warning

Tags: python, numpy, word2vec

I am using word2vec. When I am using the doesnt_match function it is showing a warning. Can anyone help:

venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py:876: FutureWarning: arrays to stack must be passed as a "sequence" type such as list or tuple. Support for non-sequence iterables such as generators is deprecated as of NumPy 1.16 and will raise an error in the future.
  vectors = vstack(self.word_vec(word, use_norm=True) for word in used_words).astype(REAL)

CODE:

```
if len(words) > 1:
    print(type(words))
    test = model.wv.doesnt_match(words)
    return test
else:
    return words
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the context manager for suppressing a FutureWarning. Hope they'll fix it in the gensim package before it breaks.

```
import warnings
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
    w2v_model.wv.doesnt_match(['the', 'and', 'or'])

# Output: 'or'

w2v_model.wv.doesnt_match(['the', 'and', 'or'])

# Output: 
# C:\Installs\Python\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py:877: 
# FutureWarning: arrays to stack must be passed as a "sequence" type such as list or 
# tuple. Support for non-sequence iterables such as generators is deprecated as of NumPy 
# 1.16 and will raise an error in the future.
# vectors = vstack(self.word_vec(word, use_norm=True) for word in used_words).astype(REAL)
# or
```

Answer (score -1):

vstack() should take a list as argument
so change the following code to get away from the FutureWarning

```
from
vectors = vstack(self.word_vec(word, use_norm=True) for word in used_words).astype(REAL)
to
vectors = vstack(list(self.word_vec(word, use_norm=True) for word in used_words)).astype(REAL)
```